# SQL - Selecting unique values from one column then filtering based on another

Tags: sql

I've had a search around and have seen quite a few questions about selecting distinct values, but none of them seem close enough to my query to be able to help. This is the scenario

```
ID   Product_ID   Product_type
123  56789        A
123  78901        B
456  12345        A
789  45612        B
```

The SQL I need would be to search in a table similar to the above, and bring back the rows where the `Product_type` is `B` but only if the `ID` related to it exists once within the table.

So in this case it would bring back only

```
789  45612        B
```

The SQL I have tried based on what I've found so far was

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID)
FROM "TABLE"
WHERE "PRODUCT_TYPE" = 'B'
```

As well as

```
SELECT *                        
FROM   "TABLE"
WHERE  "PRODUCT_TYPE" = 'B'       
GROUP BY "ID"              
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
```

And neither have worked

Comment: First, DISTIINCT is not a function on a value, it works on the whole selected rows. "SELECT DISTINCT(ID), col2" eq "SELECT DISTINCT ID, col2" eq "SELECT DISTINCT ID, (col2)" etc

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way via a list of IDs appearing once:

```
select * from T where Product_type = 'B' and id in (
select id from T
    group by id
    having count(id) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Soltuion 1: Use a sub-query to count id's.

```
select * from table t1
where Product_type = 'B'
  and (select count(*) from table
       where id = t1.id) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` for this type of query.  However, you cannot filter down to the `'B'`s *before* the aggregation.

So, try this:

```
SELECT t.id, MAX(t.product_id) as product_id,
       MAX(t.product_type) as product_type                   
FROM "TABLE" t
GROUP BY "ID"              
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND
       MAX(PRODUCT_TYPE) = 'B';
```

This may look a little bit arcane.  But the `having` clause is guaranteeing that there is only one row and that row has a `'B'`.  Hence the `MAX()` functions are returning the max from that one row -- which is the value on that row.

EDIT:

Many databases will also allow you to take advantage of window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as id_cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where t.product_type = 'B' and id_cnt = 1;
```