# Using SQL in Domo to apply multiple groups or filters

Tags: sql, sorting, filtering, unique, domo

I am trying to filter for unique UserIDs and then see which IDs have a value of >1 in another column. I have tried pretty much every example from [SQL - Selecting unique values from one column then filtering based on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324112/sql-selecting-unique-values-from-one-column-then-filtering-based-on-another) and at least 1 or two more sites but I cant find the appropriate links for that as it turned out to be a little unrelated anyways.

An example of the relevant columns of my dataset are as follows:

```
+---------+-----------+
| UserIDs | EventType |
+---------+-----------+ 
| 100     | Start     |
| 100     | Start     |
| 100     | Finish    |
| 100     | Finish    |
| 200     | Start     |
| 200     | Start     |
| 200     | Start     |
| 200     | Finish    |
| 200     | Finish    |
| 200     | Finish    |
| 300     | Start     |
| 400     | Start     |
| 400     | Finish    |
+---------+-----------+
```

What I am trying to figure out is how many users triggered EventType-Finish more than once. The data I would want from the example above would be:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| Total # of students that battled more than once|
+------------------------------------------------+  
| 2                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+ *edited*
```

None of the `Group By` stuff seems right because it would just compress the other rows into each other?

For the record I am very new to `SQL` and programming in general so try not to be too technical in your answer. Anytime I get remotely close to thinking I have solved it, I run it and it gives me syntax errors so I have no idea where else to turn.

*Sorry guys I wrote the output incorrectly, I am actually just looking for the number of students who triggered `Finish` more than once.* Also, what would I use in place of a table name eg: `FROM "TABLE"` since Domo has a kind of strange way of breaking up the hierarchy. For context, my table is called "Metrics Data" so trying to type that into the table name generally converts `data` into `SQL` code.

[Attempt at answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIUHn.png)

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.  You get syntax errors, we could have a look and get you on your way to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer,

```
SELECT UserId,COUNT(1) [# of Finishes] 
FROM Your_Table
WHERE EventType='Finish'
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(1)>1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do some conditional aggregation with help of `case` expressions

```
SELECT 
      UserIDs [UserID],
      SUM(CASE(EventType) WHEN 'Finish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [# of Finishes]
FROM <table> GROUP BY UserIDs 
HAVING SUM(CASE(EventType) WHEN 'Finish' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```

Result :

```
UserID  # of Start   
100     2            
200     3
```